# Get distance for mapbox-gl-directions

Tags: routing, mapbox-gl-js

Using the following code, how do I get the distance of the route directions?  I want to run some math against the length.

````
      container: 'map', // container id
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
      center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
      zoom: 9 // starting zoom
  });
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

  var directions = new MapboxDirections({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  })

  map.on('load', () => {
    directions.setOrigin([locations[0].longitude, locations[0].latitude]);
    directions.setDestination(userLocation);
  });

  map.addControl(directions, 'bottom-left');```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the length of the routes from the following code

```js
// Docs for route event is here:
// https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#on`enter code here`
directions.on("route", e => {
    // routes is an array of route objects as documented here:
    // https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#route-object
    let routes = e.route

    // Each route object has a distance property
    console.log("Route lengths", routes.map(r => r.distance))
})
```